# jqGrid cell not saving when switching cell

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have this jqGrid. Rows can be added dynamically. But only 1 row at a time. Now when i want to fill the row i can insert data into one cell, but when I go to the next cell previous one will lose its data. Insted of saving data it just discards it.

Using jqGrid 4.7.  When adding new row the id is "uusSoiduk".

This part of the code, i still havent found the full code. It describes the basic setup of the cells. Issue is that all cells that have edittype custom lose their data when they lose focus.

```
{name:'regNr', editable:true, width:100, resizable: false, title: false, search: false, fixed: true,
                    editoptions: {dataEvents:[{type:'change', fn: function}], maxlength: 32},
                    cellattr: attr,
                    editrules: {
                        custom: true,
                        custom_func: func
                    }
                },
                {name:'liik', editable:true, width:80, resizable: false, title: false, search: false, fixed: true,
                    edittype:'custom',
                    editoptions: {
                        dataEvents:[{type:'change', fn:func}],
                        custom_element: type,
                        custom_value: jqGridCustomElementValue
                    },
                    editrules: {
                        custom: true,
                        custom_func: func
                    }
                },
       deepempty: true,
        datatype: 'json',
        autowidth: true,
        shrinkToFit: true,
        sortname: 'id',
        sortorder: 'asc',
        autoencode:false,
        scrollOffset: 0,
        height: '100%',
        width: '100%',
        rowNum: 1000,
        pgbuttons: false,
        pgtext: false,
        viewrecords: false,
        caption: '${g.message(code:'soiduk.table.caption')}',
        pager: '#soidukPagernav',
        loadui: "disable",
        gridview: true,
        hoverrows: true,
        rownumbers: false,
        hiddengrid: true,
```

Comment: Sorry, but it's absolutely unclear what you do. Which editing mode you use? Which version of jqGrid you use (can use) and from which fork of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7)? You should include JavaScript code, which you use and include some test data (at least two rows). By the way one can't first add rows and then fill the data. The rows are always *with the data* (even with empty strings). Additionally, it's very important to know, which ids you use for the rows

Comment: @Oleg i added more info. I cant add more atm since im also missing info about this.

Comment: You wrote "When adding new row the id is "uusSoiduk"". Every row have to have **unique** id. It's strange that you write about *the same* value for new string. The part `fn: function` in `regNr` is wrong. The options, which you included, don't contain `cellEdit: true`. Thus I suppose that you use inline editing mode. You wrote "when I go to the next cell previous one will lose its data". I suppose that `change` event handlers (`fn` functions) could be the origin of the problem. `custom_value: jqGridCustomElementValue` with unknown code could ne another reason.

Comment: Error was that in some other ticket within another taks some additional check were added to a the cells. And these check allways passed and cleared the cells. Since this code is so spread out on multiple js files it was difficult to find.